Avoiding repetition of uncountable nouns
I would like to know if we can use "one" to avoid repetition in the sentence below in spite of the fact that initial word is not a countable noun? or we should repeat the initial word instead?

Why eating unhealthy food when you have enough money to eat - healthy (food) or healthy one?


So many problems here: 'Why eat unhealthy foods when you have enough money to buy healthy ones?'

By the way, I don't find just using "food" a second time to be objectionable in this example.

Food is a count noun in this context.

Word forms: plural foods 1. VARIABLE NOUN A1
...frozen foods.

Hence we could use ones or others:

Why eat unhealthy foods when you have enough money to buy healthy ones (or types or alternatives).


It's a count noun here because it means 'types of food'. It isn't always.

Do you say - one food, two foods?

Thanks, @Kate Bunting.  I have edited my first sentence.
